# Problem with vision data retrieval using GetVissionDetectionStateAsync()

Tags: dji-sdk

We're using the Windows SDK with a Mavic Air and trying to get vision data from it. Using

`GetVissionDetectionStateAsync()`

We're trying to get the distance from an obstacle. The problem is, the function seems to be working and giving values, but the value is not right. I'm getting mostly "TAIL" in the "position" field of `VissionDetectionState`, and some times "NOSE", but the `obstacleDistanceInMeters` field is always zero. Can you please help me with this problem?

Here's a picture of our sample app: 
https://ibb.co/k90JtsX

Comment: Please do not link to an outside source for the picture. Upload it, instead, directly to the question. You can use the [edit] link to do so. Also, please include sample data and the code you're using in the quesiton - as text. Do not post any images of code since that is difficult to read and can't be copied/pasted for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late, but it could help somebody else.

Inside the `VissionDetectionState` there is a list of `ObstacleDetectionSector`, this list contains the warning level and the distance of each one of the sectors.

In my case I am using the Mavic Air and the lenght of the list is 4.